# "Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments" error in linq query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to run the following query in LinqPad and the above error keeps coming up for line 10.

```
From c in Courses Where c.CourseID = 212
From cc in c.CourseContents Where cc.Active And Not cc.Deleted Order By cc.OrderIndex
Group cc by c Into Content = Group
Select New With {
    c,
    .Content = From cc in Content Select New With {
        .id = cc.CourseContentID,
        .content = If(cc.ContentTypeID = 1, 
        from a in Assessments Where a.AssessmentID = cc.ContentID select a, 
        If (cc.ContentTypeID = 2, from cf in CourseFiles Where cf.CourseFileID = cc.ContentID select cf,
        from ct in CourseTexts Where ct.CourseTextID = cc.ContentID select ct))     
    }
}
```

I've tried adding select foo = cf but that doesn't help.

How can I fix this query?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and thought I'd see if there were any open questions on SO that need this answer.

The line with the problem:

```
If (cc.ContentTypeID = 2, from cf in CourseFiles Where cf.CourseFileID = cc.ContentID select cf,
```

Whats is happening is that the last comma is ambiguous. It's possible to select multiple items, like `select x, y, z, ...`, and so that last comma is interpreted that way, expecting another identifier. To fix this, put parentheses around the entire From...Select statement.

Like this:

```
If (cc.ContentTypeID = 2, (from cf in CourseFiles Where cf.CourseFileID = cc.ContentID select cf),
```